# Curl in shell script not working with payload as variable

Tags: shell, jenkins, curl

I am new to shell. I am using curl in my Jenkins job.

I am getting the expected output if I hardcode the payload in the curl request

```
curl -i -X POST $url --header "'Content-Type: application/json'" --data-raw {"deployed": true}
```

But when I try and store it as a variable, I see I am getting errors, even though the curl output I get as part of the Jenkins pipeline is exactly the same

```
payload='{"deployed": true}'
curl -i -X POST $url --header "'Content-Type: application/json'" --data-raw $payload
```

Need help in understanding how are the different

Comment: The single quotes around the Content-type header makes it a wrong request. Also, drop the `-X POST` as it doesn't belong there. (neither explains your problem though)

Comment: please include how you execute curl in jenkins specifically. are you using Free-Style job or a Pipeline job?